# Deploy an ASP.NET Core endpoint on a custom domain using IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, binding

**Having this little demo:**

***Controller:***

```
  public class CrotolamoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/")]
        public async Task<String> test()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
```

***launchSettings.json:***

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://www.crotolamo.com",
      "sslPort": 443
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://www.crotolamo.com",
      "sslPort": 443,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Deploys correctly on Visual Studio, but unfortunately Postman is unable to send an HTTP POST request to it

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [www.crotolamo.com](http://www.crotolamo.com)

Same error occurs when deploying the app using IIS and Windows Server 2019. Using the following configuration:

Binding:

- Type: https
- IP address: All Unassigned
- Port: 443
- Host Name [www.crotolamo.com](http://www.crotolamo.com)
- SSL Certificate:IIS Express Development Certificate

The error is the same.

**Question**

The only way it works is using localhost. How could I change my configuration, to use this custom domain insted of localhost? Any help will be appreciated.

**Things I tried without success**

Adding the line to the hosts file on my Windows 10 development machine

127.0.0.1 [www.crotolamo.com](http://www.crotolamo.com)

Comment: By default, the VS generated `applicationHost.config` for IIS Express only contains localhost site bindings, so what you tried won't work unless you hack that file as well. If you do want to test your web app with more settings like this, host it on IIS so that you can easily make changes in IIS Manager.

Comment: Your comment pointed me to a solution, thank you Lex Li. The odd thing is that the same problem happened with IIS on Windows Server 2019. I wonder if applicationHost.config fix will also correct the IIS behaviour once the project is deployed in production.

Answer (score 0):

User Lex Li gave me the following hint towards a solution: With the following changes, the Visual Studio 2022 project running on the custom domain can now be browsed from the browser or Postman in the development machine.

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://www.crotolamo.com",
      "sslPort": 443
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Chostomo": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://www.crotolamo.com",
      "sslPort": 443,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**On your hosts file, add the following lines:**

- 127.0.0.1       crotolamo.com
- 127.0.0.1       [www.crotolamo.com](http://www.crotolamo.com)

**Then edit the file**

> .vs\yorProject\config\applicationhost.config

**Original**

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

**Changed**

```
    <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

Still pending to implement of the changes on IIS on Windows Server 2019, will edit the post accordingly.